# JSON-RPC call from iOS homescreen bookmark?

Tags: ios, json

Would it be possible to have a bookmark on my iPhone homescreen which calls a URL with a url-encoded json rpc?
If yes, what way is there to get it on the iPhone? Enter it manually in safari and then add the bookmark?

Answer (score 1):

Yes! Why not. If you can open the URL in Safari, you can also save it as a bookmark.